# SOAtest integration with HP ALM

Tags: integration, parasoft

I followed this documentation:

https://docs.parasoft.com/display/SOAVIRT9103/Using+HP+ALM+and+HP+Quality+Center+with+SOAtest

And chose VAPI-XP Test Type Configuration and Test Creation methodology to integrate HP ALM with SOATest. To an extent, I was able to modify  HPQualityCenter.txt. However, when i execute, I get runtime error:

> Could not parse the SOATest WSDL document.

I get 404 page not found when I try to access WSDL document in the URL:

http://svpparasoft:8080/axis2/services/SOAtestService?wsdl.

Due to organization's restrictions, I am not able to post the entire edited txt file. Requesting help on what fields need to be modified in the txt file to enable the integration.

Comment: hi, can anyone help?

Comment: I saw you have an extra space in the URL after the 8080, are you sure it's needed? Maybe that's why you're getting the 404. http://svpparasoft: 8080/axis2/services/SOAtestService?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are getting 404 error I suspect that you have to use different port for connection.
By default SOAtest server is using port 9080 for http or 9443 for https.

Please, check the following:

1. Is SOAtest server running? If not, start it by pressing green "Play"
   button in SOAtest Server View.
2. Are you able to get content of wsdl, if you replace 8080 with 9080
   in wsdl's URL?
3. Do you have proper license which allows you to start SOAtest server?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to proceed to the next step after changing 8080 to 9080.